# Fractional vertex cover number may not be feasible? Very confusing!

Tags: graphs, linear-programming

For my project, I try to use **minimum fractional vertex cover number (MFVC)**. (Please find below definition details) MFVC can be formulated as optimal solution of a linear program relaxation.

However I find that every linear program relaxation is either infeasible, unbounded, or has an optimum solution.

Does is mean that MFVC may not exist, or may not be a finite number, but MFVC is less or equal to minimum vertex cover number? Very confusing! :(

Many thanks!

---

*Definitions:*

**K-uniform hypergraph:**
[image]

**Minimum fractional vertex cover number (MFVC):** [**link**](https://repozytorium.amu.edu.pl/bitstream/10593/10973/1/Mieczkowska_Katarzyna_rozprawa.pdf) (*on page 8*)

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOfGF.png]

**MFVC as linear programming relaxation:**

The minimum fractionl vertex cover $\tau^* (G)$ in a k-uniform hypergraph $G=(V,E)$ is 
 $\min \sum_{v\in V}w (v)$

such that $0 \le w(v) \le 1$,

and for each $e \in E$, we have $\sum_{v\in e} w(v) \ge 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The linear program defining the minimum fractional vertex cover always has an optimal solution. The fact that some linear programs are infeasible or unbounded doesn’t mean that *every* linear program is infeasible or unbounded.

To give another example, sometimes you can’t divide by $x$. But if $x$ is a positive integer, then you can always divide by $x$. This in no way contradicts the fact that there exist $x$ that you can’t divide by - it just means that this complication doesn’t occur for positive integers.

To see that the minimum fractional vertex cover always exists, we have to show that the relaxation is *feasible* and *bounded* (from below). To see that it is feasible, notice that if you assign $w(v) = 1$ for all $v$, then you get a feasible solution. To see that it is bounded from below, notice that $w(v) \geq 0$ guarantees that the objective functions is always non-negative.

Comment: Yuval, thank you for answering my question. I really appreciate it! ^_^